# How to show electrostatic interactions in Pymol on the wanted residue

Tags: protein-structure, docking, pymol, structural-biology

I have the following Pymol visual,
The green molecule is receptor and red/yellow is the ligand.
In the ligand I highlighted Lysine (K) residue as yellow.

[image]

What I want to do is to highlight and draw the electro static contact of the ligand especially with Lysine residue. Like this in Pymol:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

Depends whether you work with named selections which is preferable and helpful if you want to use this Pymol session for future images. In this case, use the distance command for your two selections, one being the N of the K in your ligand and the other the O of the E of your protein.

Full syntax and examples here: https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Distance

If you need a quick solution: in the menu Wizard, click on Measurement. Then click on the two atoms where you want the dotted line to appear in between.

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to see the `electrostatic` contact - proton and electron - like shown in my OP.

Comment: This answer is still valid, you simply click the hydrogen not the nitrogen for your distance. However, I would suggest that you do `color atomic, not element C` as you currently have all elements coloured in and it's well confusing...